# MSTest Unit Test with List<> returned not working

Tags: unit-testing, generics, mstest

I have a pretty simple unit test that is testing the proper generation of a generic `List<SelectListItem>` .

```
    [TestMethod()]
public void PopulateSelectListWithSeperateTextAndValueLists()
{
    //Arrange
    SetupDisplayAndValueLists();
    bool allOption = false;

    //Act
    List<SelectListItem> result = ControllerHelpers.PopulateSelectList(valueList, displayList, allOption);

    //Assert
    Assert.AreEqual(expected, result);
}
```

The Assert always returns false, even though I have checked and confirmed that both objects have the same exact values.

Is there any special considerations when unit testing return results that are generics?

**Updated with new tests and their status**

```
Assert.AreEqual(4, result.Count); //passes

Assert.AreEqual(result[0].Text, expected[0].Text, "0 element is not found");//passes
Assert.AreEqual(result[1].Text, expected[1].Text, "1 element is not found");//passes
Assert.AreEqual(result[2].Text, expected[2].Text, "2 element is not found");//passes
Assert.AreEqual(result[3].Text, expected[3].Text, "3 element is not found");//passes

Assert.AreEqual(result[0].Value, expected[0].Value, "0 element is not found");//passes
Assert.AreEqual(result[1].Value, expected[1].Value, "1 element is not found");//passes
Assert.AreEqual(result[2].Value, expected[2].Value, "2 element is not found");//passes
Assert.AreEqual(result[3].Value, expected[3].Value, "3 element is not found");//passes

Assert.IsTrue(result.Contains(expected[0]), "0 element is not found"); //doesn't pass
Assert.IsTrue(result.Contains(expected[1]), "1 element is not found"); //doesn't pass
Assert.IsTrue(result.Contains(expected[2]), "2 element is not found"); //doesn't pass
Assert.IsTrue(result.Contains(expected[3]), "3 element is not found"); //doesn't pass

Assert.AreEqual(expectedList, result); //doesn't pass
```

Answer (score 5):

Use the [CollectionAssert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.collectionassert%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) class instead of the Assert class. You can choose to validate that items are in the same order, or just that they both have the same items overall.

Again though, if the items in your collection are reference types and not value types, it may not compare them how you want. (Though strings will work fine)

Update: Since you're comparing the .Text property of those items, you could try to use LINQ to return the Text properties as a collection. Then, CollectionAssert will work exactly as you want it for comparing the actual and expected collections of Text.

Comment: I had no idea CollectionAssert existed! But it still doesn't work. I've tried both CollectionAssert.AreEqual and CollectionAssert.AreEquivilent, but both fail: "Failed PopulateSelectListWithOneList CollectionAssert.AreEqual failed. (Element at index 0 do not match.)". However, the tests that check .Count and the individual elements still pass (see above), so I know that this is not the case. I'm starting to suspect it has something to do with the SelectListItem object and how it determines equality...

Comment: @morganpdx - Just to be sure, what values are you passing in to .AreEqual() or .AreEquivilent()? If its just the lists of SelectListItem objects, then its testing if they are the exact same instantiated objects instead of if their text/value properties are the same (Apj's answer explains this as well).

Answer (score 0):

The issue here might not be related to generics, but to do with what the equality of 2 lists is implemented as. Equals() on a list may be the Object implementation, checking if it's the same instance only, and not comparing contents.

When I need to test the contents of a list have been populated as expected using C# and mbUnit, I tend to check the count is equal, and then check each item within the list. Alternately, if I'm not bothered about the order of the items in the results list, I can check it contains each.

```
Assert.AreEqual(3, result.Count);
Assert.Contains(expectedList[0], result);
Assert.Contains(expectedList[1], result);
Assert.Contains(expectedList[2], result);
```

**Edit:**

It looks like SelectListItem uses the `Object.Equals()` implementation, and only checks for referential equality (same instance). There's 2 solutions which come to mind.

1. Write a method to check a list contains an item with a given text and value, then reuse that. It's a little cleaner, but not hugely so, unless you have more tests.
2. Use linq statements to select all the text, and all the values, from the result list. Then use Asserts with CollectionEquivalentConstraints to check the lists are equal. *(Note I haven't tested this myself, and am going off online documentation).*

   var texts = result.Select(x => x.Text).ToList();
   var values = result.Select(x => x.Value).ToList();

   Assert.That(texts, Is.EquivalentTo(new string[] { expectedList[0].Text, expectedList[1].Text, ... });
   Assert.That(values, Is.EquivalentTo(new string[] { expectedList[0].Value, expectedList[1].Value, ... });

You could also simplify this significantly by generating your expected values as 2 separate lists. You could likely also generate a `Dictionary`, and provide `Keys` and `Values` as the equivalent lists.

Comment: Yes, that's what I was going to do next. I was just trying to see if I could keep it simple, but apparentlly not :P  Thanks!

Comment: I tried the .Contains approach, but it still isn't passing. I decided to bite the bullet and check each value of each element, and everything passes there. Ugh.  I updated the question with all the tests, and noted which pass and which don't.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim i As Integer
    Assert.AreEqual(expected.Count, actual.Count)

    For i = 0 To expected.Count - 1
        Assert.AreEqual(expected.ToList.Item(i).ID, actual.ToList.Item(i).ID)
    Next
```

In this case I am comparing the IDs, I suppose you could compare any value-type key field and get the same. This passed, while none of the CollectionAssert methods did me any good.

Lisa Morgan